# IE & Edge, preventDefault() not working on laptop with touch and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I have following element:

```
<a id="buttonNext" href="somepage">        
</a>
```

and following javascript:

```
 $(document).on('click', "#buttonNext", function (event) {
        if (isNavigating === true || $htmlTp.isUnloading()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

        isNavigating = true;
        window.location.href = "somepage";
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

when activating this anchor by touch in IE and Egde the preventDefault() does not work, which means that the navigation to "somepage" is executed twice. This happens only in IE and Edge, other browser work. Also, this code works when activating this anchor by mouse.

Did somebody succeed to use preventDefault() for touch on a computer where touch and mouse is used at the same time?

Comment: Are you sure it's the preventDefault() not working, or is the `(isNavigating === true || $htmlTp.isUnloading())` condition not hitting? The latter is ***far*** more likely

Comment: well you replace the page so what exactly is the prevent default going to do....

Comment: yeah, I am sure it it's not the "IsNavigating" clause. I debugged it in the browser. Actually, if I remove the href from anchor, it navigates just once. PreventDefault is helping to prevent fast double clicking on the anchor while navigating...

Comment: additinally, doesn't make sense that this behavior happens only when tapping on the anchor by touch in IE and Edge...